# Cambiar formato a fecha

Tags: javascript, regex, date, material-ui

estoy recibiendo una fecha por medio de props, que viene de mi base de datos en mongo, la fecha viene de esta manera

```
2022-11-17T19:41:12.683Z
```

Lo que necesito es que me salga en un formato tipo `dd/mm/yyyy`, intente con el `toLocaleDateString` pero no me funciono alguna otra opción?

Dejo el codigo donde la estoy mostrando en pantalla

```
 <Divider>
          <Chip label={data.createdAt} />
        </Divider>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías utilizar el método [**`slice()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) para extraer los primeros 10 caracteres de la fecha que obtienes, en este caso nos devuelve **`2022-11-17`**; y ya con este resultado obtenido le damos el formato de **`dd/mm/yyyy`** con una expresión regular:

```js
var date = '2022-11-17T19:41:12.683Z';

function format(date) {
  var result = date.slice(0, 10); // Nos devuelve => "2022-11-17"
  return result.replace(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/g, '$3/$2/$1');
}

console.log(format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente esas fechas vienen de tipo  *string*, para poder usar el metodo `toLocaleDateString` necesitas parsarlo a tipo *Date*.

Intenta hacer lo siguiente

```
 <Divider>
      <Chip label={new Date(data.createdAt).toLocaleDateString()} />
  </Divider>
```

Si te funciona entonces ya puedes optimizar la solucion.